# Border opacity - React Native

Tags: react-native, border, opacity

I applied a border to a 'View' and I want to know how can I change the opacity of the border.

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}> </View>

mainContainer: {
 borderWidth: 2,
 borderColor: '#ddd',
 ....
 opacity: 2,
 ....
}
```

It is not working when I applied the style as above.

Comment: Can you set it with rgba? E.g. `borderColor: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);` The last parameter is opacity

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do try using `borderColor: 'rgba(158, 150, 150, .5)'` where the last parameter defines opacity and it ranges from 0 to 1

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the border opacity in Android in react native elevation property is used. But in ios you can use

IOS ONLY

=> shadowColor

=> shadowOffset

=> shadowOpacity

=> shadowRadius

properties to change the shadow opacity.

for further documentation you can check 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.6/view-style-props

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we can also use `#33DDDDDD`. Adding 33 before the 6-character hex color indicates opacity of 20% (0.2). Kindly note that if it's mobile, it should be pre added while web is post (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#hex-notation).

Kudos to this: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

To avoid any underlying conflicts though, use the accepted answer <the rgb() one>. Cheers!